# Catching two exceptions and handling each one differently in java

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputFile = "PullFrom.txt";
    String outputFile = "Output.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true));
    int ID;

    while (input.hasNextLine() && input.hasNextInt()) {
        ID = input.nextInt();

         for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
         try {
            out.write("case "+ID+ ":");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("setRandomWalk(false);");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("break;");
            out.newLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't Find " +inputFile );
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't create " + outputFile );
         }
}
     out.close();
     input.close();}}}
```

I am trying to catch `FileNotFoundException` but my `BufferedWriter` requires that I have `IOException`, so I am trying to catch them both.

I am getting this in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: PullFrom.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at reader.PullFrom.main(PullFrom.java:15)
```

If someone could please explain to me what exactly `IOException` is as well that would be great, thank you!

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`: it just indicates a more specific problem that has occurred whilst doing IO-related things. As such, `catch (IOException e)` would catch both.

Comment: So if I wanted to handle "both" differently, could I do that and still catch them both with IOException?

Comment: If you want to handle them differently, put the catch for the subclass before the catch for the superclass, as you have done. However, you aren't reaching the catch blocks in your code - see my answer. Also, you can't handle *both*, you can only handle 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post a *minimal* example of the code which generates the problem. This is all that is necessary to generate the exception posted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String inputFile = "PullFrom.txt";
  String outputFile = "Output.txt";
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
}
```

You are getting a `FileNotFoundException` here because `PullFrom.txt` does not exist. Because `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`, it is handled by the `throws IOException` in the method signature.

Because you're not handling the exception in this method, it is being thrown from the `main` method, and so is being handled by the uncaught exception handler. You'd need to surround the new Scanner(new File(inputFile)) in a try/catch block if you want execution to continue despite the exception.

Comment: I purposefully removed my PullFrom.txt file so that I could set up a sort of error handler to print out "Can't find PullFrom.txt" whenever the file is missing, however it throws an exception to the console window rather than printing out my text.

Comment: That's because you're not handling the exception - it is being thrown from the `main` method, and so is being handled by the uncaught exception handler. You'd need to surround the `new Scanner(new File(inputFile))` in a try/catch block.

Comment: If I do that, my "input" (which is actually my scanner) variable cannot be resolved.

Comment: Declare the `input` variable before the try/catch block. However, if the exception occurs, `input` won't be assigned a value - how would you then be able to use it?

Comment: How can I declare my input variable when "input" is my scanner.         Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));

Comment: `Scanner input; try { input = ... } catch (IOException e) { ... }`.

Comment: This worked for me, however in order for Scanner input; to work I had to initialize it by making it Scanner input = null;, and now I get a nullPointerException.

Comment: Well, yes. You're not changing its value from null, because the FileNotFoundException occurs before the assignment takes place. In any case, if you are asking it to read a file which doesn't exist, it will never be able to give you any data back: throwing the exception is the right thing to do in this case; logging a message and returning is a (worse) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

An IOException would cover other Exceptions rather than just FileNotFoundExceptions - e.g. if the file can't be accessed.

FileNotFoundException is actually a sub class of IOException, so you could just catch IOException and this would work for both cases.

Also - do you mean to do the e.printStackTrace()? This is typically speaking an anti pattern - it looks ugly and it would result in the output you see in your log here.

Comment: I did not mean to do the printStackTrace(); Eclipse added it when I added my throw/catch clause. I removed it from the code as well as my FileNotFoundException catch clause but I still get the same output in my log.

Comment: The stack-trace is coming from the Java platform itself (the exception gets propagated outside `main()`), not from the `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner can throw a `FileNotFoundException` if source is not found, you should put this:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true));
```

in a block try/catch